# Why does npm install throws Type link error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, tensorflow, npm

I am installing this repo on my PC https://github.com/vladmandic/human

When I download it and run `npm install`, it shows error like this:
[image]

Do you guys have any idea how to solve it?
I'm using Windows 11, Node 18

I have tried this https://github.com/vladmandic/human/wiki/Install but it does not solve the issue.